# Using "WebBrowser Control" functionality in Monodroid

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.android

can I use the WebBrowser Control (available in C#) in Monodroid to create a simple web browser for Android. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android equivalent is WebView:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/User_Interface/web_view